# Extract parameterised type from self in scala

Tags: scala

I have class with parameterised type

```
abstract class Worker[T] {
  def conf1: ...
  def conf2: ...
  def doWork ...
}

abstract class SpecializedWorker[T: TypeTag] extends Worker[T] {
  //some behavior overriden (used fields from Trait that i want create)
}
```

I want to create trait that can be mixed to Worker.

```
trait Extension {
  self: Worker[_] =>      

  def someParameter: ... // only several workers can have that. thats why i need trait
  def produceSpecializedWorker = new SpecializedWorker[???]() {}
}
```

How to extract type information from self to replace ???

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? Do you mean you want to extract the type of worker from self? Why don't you do `trait Extension[T] { self: Worker[T] }`?

Comment: because i will need set type T twice. It is possible workaround but is not clear `class SomeWorker extends Worker[SomeCaseClass] with Extension[SomeCaseClass]`

Comment: What do you mean by *"set type T twice"*?

Comment: `class SomeWorker extends Worker[SomeCaseClass] with Extension[SomeCaseClass]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to extract a type parameter:

```
trait Extension {
  self: Worker[_] =>      
  def mkSpWorker[T](implicit ev: this.type <:< Worker[T]) = new SpecializedWorker[T]() {}
}
```

But I wouldn't recommend that :) You could define a type member in `Worker` that can be used in `Extension`.

```
abstract class Worker[T] {
  type TT = T
}

trait Extension {
  self: Worker[_] =>      
  def mkSpWorker = new SpecializedWorker[TT]() {}
}
```

Or you could just consider giving `Extension` a type parameter. It's not such a big deal, I think.